# Show that $\{\frac{n^2}{n^2+n}\}$ is convergent

Tags: analysis, proof-verification

> Use only the Archimedean Property of $\mathbb{R}$ to show  $\{\frac{n^2}{n^2+n}\}$ is convergent

---

Let $a_n=\{\frac{n^2}{n^2+n}\}=\{\frac{n}{n+1}\}=\{1-\frac{1}{n+1}\}=\{1\}-\{\frac{1}{n+1}\}$.

$\{1\}$ is convergent to $1$. Show $\{\frac{1}{n+1}\}$ is convergent. So let $\epsilon>0$. By the Archimedean Property, there exists an index $N$ such that $1/N<\epsilon$. So for all $n\geq N$, we have $1/n\leq 1/N$. Then we have $$\frac{1}{n+1}\leq\frac{1}{n}\leq\frac{1}{N}<\epsilon$$

Then we have $\vert1/(n+1)-0\vert=1/(n+1)<\epsilon$ which shows that $1/(n+1)$ is converged to $0$; thus $b_n$ is converged to $1$.

---

I am not sure that is valid to do $\{1-\frac{1}{n+1}\}=\{1\}-\{\frac{1}{n+1}\}$ because it looks right to me. If that is not valid, can anyone give me a hit or suggestion to show the sequence is convergent? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to know that the sum of two convergent sequences is convergent for your argument to be 100% okay. This is probably "not known" now (if it is, your proof is fine).

You are on the right track, your proof only needs to show that $\left|(1-\frac{1}{n+1})-1\right|<\epsilon$ which you basically did!

Comment: How do I get $|(1-1/(n+1))-1$, I am trying to show $a_n$ is converged to  $1$

Comment: @Simple First, a language thing. We say that "$a_n$ converges to $1$", NOT "$a_n$ is converged to $1$". Second of all, that is the definition of convergent. That is for all $\epsilon>0$ there is an $N$ such that $n> N$ implies $|a_n-L|<\epsilon$. Just letting $a_n=1-\frac{1}{n+1}$ and $L=1$.

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to simply note that, if $n \geq 1$, then
$$
\bigg| \frac{n^{2}}{n^{2}+n} - 1 \bigg| = \frac{n}{n^{2}+n} < \frac{1}{n}.
$$